# Security between app and server?

Tags: ios, node.js, ssl, authorization, basic-authentication

I know that there are a ton of threads about this. But I'm still confused.

I've got an app that making request to my server(nodeJS) to get JSON-data. 
For the moment everyone can get everything at: `http://myserver/allUpdates/` with no password. They just have to know the URL.

So I thought I would do it little more secure. 
I been looking at **Basic Auth**, that seems to work by sending username and password in the header for every request.

Is that enough?

Some guys say that it doesn't do much if youre not using SSL. But it must be better than nothing, right?

I've never used SSL and it seems there is a lot to learn.

So my question is, should I bother with auth when I'm not using SSL?
Or are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some guys say that it doesn't do much if youre not using SSL. But it must be better than nothing, right?

Unfortunately, those guys are right. Basic Auth is, when sent plaintext, probably *worse* than nothing as it gives you the vague feeling of some security without any *actual* security.

This is because it is trivial to intercept network requests through a proxy or similar. If you're not used SSL then every parameter you're sending is easily and readily visible, including your basic authentication credentials.

In answer to your question *"should I bother with auth when I'm not using SSL?"* - that depends. If you want to ensure your data is only accessed by authenticated users, then it's really SSL or nothing. But if all you're trying to do is reduce the burden on your servers (i.e, rate limiting), then maybe not. I'm going to *assume* you're looking to do the former, in which case I'd recommend taking the time to get to grips with SSL. There are lots of resources out there about using Node with SSL, depending upon what additional frameworks you might be using (Express, etc).

Comment: Nice! But I'm not sure if I'll use SSL because the data is not that sensitive. And I'm not sure if I wan't to spend money on certificates. =) I'll definitely read some about it.

Comment: I hope you never build anything that alot of people use. If you do, this post where you refer to people's usernames/passwords as 'not that sensitive' will probably come back to bite you.

Comment: In my defence, the app doesn't store users data. App has a static self generated username/password that isn't unique to any user. But I agree with you that it didn't sound good at all. Maybe the data doesn't have to be sensitive to use SSL. There seems to be more benefits to use SSL than just protect data.

Answer (score 1):

SSL encrypts your requests, which means that anyone that sniffs your network traffic can't read the payload of the request.

You have two ways to auth the client to the server:

- send credentials or an API key with every request OR
- login in the client once with credentials or API key and reuse it's session

In both ways, you should use SSL and send the credentials with your POST data.